# Convert ID to the class type using Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to develop a generic crud using Spring Boot, my generic entity base class use `serializable`

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entidade<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public abstract T getId();
    public abstract T setId(T id);

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cachorro")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Cachorro extends Entidade<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cachorro_seq") 
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public Long setId(Long id) {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

So when I call rest method it throw a exception telling about the conversion, when use repository method.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstratoRepository<E extends Entidade<?>> extends JpaRepository<E, Serializable> {
}

@Repository
public interface CachorroRepository extends AbstratoRepository<Cachorro> {
}
```

Package Service

```
public interface IAbstratoService<E> {

    public List<E> carregarTodos();
    public Optional<E> carregarPeloCodigo(Serializable id);
    public void inserir(E entidade);
    public void atualizar(E entidade);
    public void deletar(Serializable id);

}

public class AbstratoServiceImpl<T extends Serializable, E extends Entidade<?>, R extends AbstratoRepository<E>>
        implements IAbstratoService<E> {

    @Autowired
    private R repositorio;

    @Override
    public List<E> carregarTodos() {
        return this.repositorio.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> carregarPeloCodigo(Serializable id) {
        return this.repositorio.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void inserir(E entidade) {
        this.repositorio.save(entidade);
    }

    @Override
    public void atualizar(E entidade) {
        this.repositorio.save(entidade);
    }

    @Override
    public void deletar(Serializable id) {
        this.repositorio.deleteById(id);
    }
}

@Service
public class CachorroService extends AbstratoServiceImpl<Long, Cachorro, CachorroRepository> {
}
```

And Resource

```
public abstract class AbstratoResource<E extends Entidade<?>, S extends IAbstratoService<E>> {

    @Autowired
    protected S service;

    @GetMapping("/carregarTodos")
    public List<E> carregarTodos() {
        return this.service.carregarTodos();
    }

    @GetMapping("/carregarPeloCodigo/{id}")
    public Optional<E> carregarPeloCodigo(@PathVariable("id") Serializable id) {
        return this.service.carregarPeloCodigo(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/inserir")
    public void inserir(E entidade) {
        this.service.inserir(entidade);
    }

    @PutMapping("/atualizar")
    public void atualizar(E entidade) {
        this.service.atualizar(entidade);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deletar")
    public void deletar(Serializable id) {
        this.service.deletar(id);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cachorro")
public class CachorroResource extends AbstratoResource<Cachorro, CachorroService> {

    @GetMapping("/criar")
    public void criar() {
        List<String> nomes = Arrays.asList("Alé", "Diana", "Enzo", "França", "Nanico", "Nina", "Leco", "Princesa", "Petruquio", "Titinha");
        for (String nome : nomes) {
            Cachorro cachorro = new Cachorro();
            cachorro.setNome(nome);
            this.service.inserir(cachorro);         
        }
    }
}
```

So I got this stack trace

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class br.com.abstrato.model.Cachorro. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.checkIdClass(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:174) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1288) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1276) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2912) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2886) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3521) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3490) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:309) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:274) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at br.com.abstrato.service.AbstratoServiceImpl.carregarPeloCodigo(AbstratoServiceImpl.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.abstrato.resource.AbstratoResource.carregarPeloCodigo(AbstratoResource.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

So I understand the stack trace, the id comes in String and I need to convert to Long, but how can I do this using generic way, I tryed to use reflection, but didn´t work.

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the error here is the following => AbstratoServiceImpl and AbstratoResource should use T and not serializable for id fields. The following is a good starting point.

```
public abstract class AbstratoResource<ID, E extends Entidade<ID>, S extends IAbstratoService<E>> {

    @Autowired
    protected S service;

    @GetMapping("/carregarTodos")
    public List<E> carregarTodos() {
        return this.service.carregarTodos();
    }

    @GetMapping("/carregarPeloCodigo/{id}")
    public Optional<E> carregarPeloCodigo(@PathVariable("id") ID id) {
        return this.service.carregarPeloCodigo(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/inserir")
    public void inserir(E entidade) {
        this.service.inserir(entidade);
    }

    @PutMapping("/atualizar")
    public void atualizar(E entidade) {
        this.service.atualizar(entidade);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deletar")
    public void deletar(ID id) {
        this.service.deletar(id);
    }
}

public interface IAbstratoService<E> {

    public List<E> carregarTodos();
    public Optional<E> carregarPeloCodigo(ID id);
    public void inserir(E entidade);
    public void atualizar(E entidade);
    public void deletar(ID id);

}

public class AbstratoServiceImpl<ID, T extends Serializable, E extends Entidade<ID>, R extends AbstratoRepository<E>>
        implements IAbstratoService<E> {

    @Autowired
    private R repositorio;

    @Override
    public List<E> carregarTodos() {
        return this.repositorio.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> carregarPeloCodigo(ID id) {
        return this.repositorio.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void inserir(E entidade) {
        this.repositorio.save(entidade);
    }

    @Override
    public void atualizar(E entidade) {
        this.repositorio.save(entidade);
    }

    @Override
    public void deletar(ID id) {
        this.repositorio.deleteById(id);
    }
}

@Service
public class CachorroService extends AbstratoServiceImpl<Long, Cachorro, CachorroRepository> {
}
```

Comment: You can also get some ideas here about generics.
https://github.com/maenolis/spring-abstract-layers

Comment: Later I will try your solution in home, thanks for your tip